# adding mouseover event to img element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="load();">
    <img src="img1.png">
    <img src="img2.png">
    <img class="img3" src="img3.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

And I want the 3rd image to go to the left when mouse is over it. (It has position: absolute; on it) using this js code

```
let img;
function load(){
  img = document.querySelector(".img3");
  img.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseover);
}
function mouseover(){
  img.style.left = "0px";
}
```

but mouseover never gets called. (Checked with logging)

Comment: The code you provided runs fine and adds the style to the element, https://jsfiddle.net/sekwtdj0/ That being said, you should really go with a css solution unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: how about ```.img3{
position: absolute;
}``` ?

Comment: Also, what browser are u on?

Comment: If your usecase is this simple you should not use JS. you should stick with CSS. Use `:hover` selector

Answer (score 0):

In your css you can use

```
.img3:hover{
  /* css here */
}
```

If you use this method you do not need to use Javascript to change css on hover it is built in to css already :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the hover method in css to achieve this, it would look something like:

```
.img3:hover {
  width: *put desired width here*;
  height: *put desired height here*;
}
```

You might need to use id tags to make the default image shrink when the img3:hover event occurs. You can find more information about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: I know workarounds, but I want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: I find the position absolute feature to be a pain to work with properly, your best bet is to alter the code in css rather than trying to play with it in javascript. You would need to have a style property in your img tag. You can create a variable called styles, and call the variable like this <img style={{ styles }} /> , and update the styles variable with a function.